# Hook for validating and rejecting frontend image upload

Tags: plugin-development, images, hooks, uploads

I am making a plugin that checks the contents of uploaded images. Right now I am testing if I am using the right hook, so I use `getimagesize()` to check the image (I am aware this is not the best/most thorough way to do this. This is just for testing the hook). If it's not an image, it will show the error message below.

[image]

I use the hook `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` and it works fine, but only at the admin dashboard (which is what the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter) suggests). I used [this plugin](https://tw.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-upload/) which allows users to upload from post/page to do the testing and the fake image uploaded successfully.

I've searched through Google and this site and most people suggest `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` or `add_attachment`. However, I am not sure `add_attachment` is the one I am looking for because according to [this site](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/attachment/) an attachment is a file uploaded from the *post edit screen*, which is still from admin dashboard. I've tested it and the error message did show up. (ps. I see people use `add_filter("add_attachment",...)` but Wordpress says this is an action hook?)

I'm also thinking just go through each file in $_FILES and then do the checking, but again I don't know which hook to use with this method.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found it after trying with several hooks.

Use 'init' and check if $_FILES is empty, if not, do what you want to do.

[init hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init)